# Minimize white space below figure

Tags: wrapfigure, setspace, appendix

I tried following a few threads to minimize the white space below my figure. It seems straightforward, but it's not working. Maybe it could be that I'm trying to do this in an Appendix environment? I would like to extend my figure from 16 cm to 18 cm (yes, there is enough space in the page for this), my attempt looks like

```
\documentclass[a4paper, leqno, oneside] {report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm, textheight=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{rotating,caption,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\section*{Appendix 5}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{A.5 my figure}

\begin{figure}[h] 
\centering
\caption{My very big picture}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-2cm}
\includegraphics[height=16cm, width=1 \linewidth]{QQmale1.png}
\label{fig:QQmale1}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not set width *and* height <ith `\includegraphics` as it will distort the figure.

Comment: You could add a command `\vspace*{-2cm}` just after `\includegraphics` . command... Also, setting the length of `\belowcaptionskip` after the `\caption` command, has no real effect in your resulting document, If you would like to set this length, you should do it before the `\caption` command

Comment: why have you used `begin{figure}[h] ` here? which is forcing the figure to be placed on a page with text when if it is large it is more natural to place it on a page on its own?

Answer (score 2):

you should reduce default share of text on page. try add `\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}` into document preamble:

```
\documentclass[demo, % only for test purposes
                a4paper, leqno, oneside] {report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{caption} % loaded second time
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
%\usepackage{booktabs}  % loaded second time
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm, textheight=23cm,
            showframe  % only for test purposes
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{rotating,caption,booktabs}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05} % <---

\begin{document}
\section*{Appendix 5}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{A.5 my figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\caption{My very big picture}
\includegraphics[height=0.88\textheight]{example-image}
\label{fig:QQmale1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]